# Feedback box location

Tags: user-feedback, location

I am designing a feedback box and I was thinking about placing it in the bottom-right corner of the website - this is where I usually come across feedback boxes or chats.

But then sometimes I see some kinds of forms or boxes that want the users attention extending from the middle of the side of the webpage. I guess I am biased in some way, because subjectively I think they're pretty annoying and I associate them automatically more with ads then reasonable feedback requests an so on.

Question: Is there the best location for the feedback box/button, so it does not annoy users?

Comment: There are different considerations depending on if it is an app on a mobile device or a website on a desktop screen for example. I think it also depends on whether the feedback should be given at any time or after they have gone through some of the userflows. It is actually hard to balance visibility with not blocking any exiting user interactions or content so it requires looking into the design in a bit more detail if you want a more accurate answer.

Comment: This is a website, so there's enough space. And also the side solution is not a bad idea considering place, because there are quite big margins, so no content would be obscured. And the feedback box would appear after some time the user spent on the site, so they'd know their way around before commenting, but it's not going to be event-based.

Comment: Even if it is a website it could be viewed on a mobile device with limited space so just be aware of that issue. The idea of a feedback box appearing after they have spent a little bit of time on the site is a good idea though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The reason you see the feedback option on your bottom right is because they are least obstructive. More than location, some options are repeated based on user's familiarity with the option. Thats the reason why Save button almost always has a floppy disk icon. Even though the hardware itself does not mean anything in this day and age.

Coming to your question. The best position for your feedback is where the user has easy access to it, while not hiding the important material on the page. Best side of the screen would be the right side...as we read Left to Right and majority of the content would be placed from the left. Prefer a floating button rather than the feedback field.

Comment: Thanks. But what do you mean by "Prefer a floating button rather than the feedback field."?

Comment: What I mean is the call to action can be a button, rather than the flat feedback input box on the left. Unless the page has space on the right to accommodate the feedback section without cluttering your UI.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Feedback tab]

**Sticky feedback tabs on the left or right side of the screen** can work well if they are not blocking important content.

When the user clicks the feedback tab, they typically slides open the panel, or open a modal window, whereupon a form is presented.

**Example** (as shown in the image) here: https://usabilla.com/

**Another example** here : https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Minimal-Side-Feedback-Form-Using-jQuery-Bootstrap-feedback-js/

Comment: That feedback box sure is a neck breaker! ;-)

Comment: Haha ... that *is* true @RobE - It does have a downside. Or should I say a side-side?